# Скрипт коментариев для сайта

Tags: скрипт

Где можно найти в просторах интернета готовый скрипт коментариев для сайта который не требует базы данных...?

Answer (score 2):

Использовал на нескольких проектах [cackle](http://cackle.ru/welcome). Ставить 5 минут, и клиентам нравится. И ресурсы вашего сервера не трогает вообще.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы имеете в виду что-то вроде гостевой книги, то они ищутся по словам "file based guestbook", например:

- [PHP Guestbook Script](http://code.google.com/p/asgbookphp/)
- [PHP Flat File Guestbook](http://www.advancebydesign.com/software/php-scripts-and-programmes/mail-and-feedback/php-flat-file-guestbook.html)
- ...